# rails_admin issue: has_many :through form doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` gem and have this `Post` model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Association
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags

  # rails_admin configuration
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :title
      field :categories
      field :tags
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is the Category field displayed as expected but Tag field is not.

[image: rails_admin issue]

Please tell me what possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags`.

Comment: Ricardo: there is no `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for `categories` but it still works.